# Python localhost and SASS

Tags: python, batch-file, sass

I am trying to combine all of my command line commands into a single .bat file, the only commands I am using are:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --insecure
```

and

```
sass --watch test.scss:test.css
```

How can I write a .bat file to run them both?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind getting too many command windows, `start` will open a new cmd console for you:

```
start python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --insecure
start sass --watch test.scss:test.css
```

Comment: I just tried that, the python server is fine, however the SASS line goes into an infinite loop, which runs the line over and over.